# Weird jquery/css animation issue on page scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

This is the page I have : http://goo.gl/H32N0U

The issue is, When the page loads for the first time... Then when I scroll down the animations does not work in most of the elements such as button below the video...
But when I scroll up, Animations starts working and when I scroll down again.. it works.

Why not very first time I scroll down after page load?

Comment: In **index.html** ,  the js(jquery &css3-animate-it.js ) are included at the bottom of the page after the html close tag, please try including them in Head tag

Comment: it didn't work. Messed up even more.

Comment: Ok, just for once include them in body but at last.

Comment: This is also didn't work. Problem is still same. It's really weird, On first scroll most animations doesn't work.. but once you scroll down then up.. it starts working normally but just not at the very first scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when the site is first loaded, every div that doing an animation is with a class name "go".. and this class is there until you scroll up the page, in this case the class is removed.

and than when you going down again and the div is shown, the class added again.

you need to remove the "go" class  2-3 seconds after the page loaded.

goodluck!

Comment: It worked!! You are awesome dude!! Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Comment: but if you notice the guarantee box on the webpage.. It is still facing the same issue even after remove "go" class

Comment: this is because the go class added to the element to soon..
some thing is trigger the addClass "go" to this element some where in the middle of the page.